# MASM64 running 64bit Mode instead of 64bit compatibility mode

Tags: windows, windows-8, 64-bit, masm

ML64.exe seems to compile and run in 64bit compatibility mode instead of 64bit mode. I assume this because it seems virtualized in windows 8. Is there a way to force, or compile into, 64bit mode in windows 8?

Comment: ML64.exe is a 32-bit program that generates 64-bit object files.  There is no 64-bit version of it.  Assuming that ML64 must be a 64-bit process just because it can generate 64-bit obj files makes as little sense as assuming that it was written in assembly because it can parse assembly code.

Comment: My question is can ml64 compile code for 64bit mode? My question is not "can ml64 run in 64bit mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ML64.exe can compile on a 32-bit Windows system, since it is a 32-bit program, and on a 64-bit Windows system, since all 64-bit Windows systems have the WoW64 subsystem that runs 32-bit programs in a 32-bit environment. Therefore, ML64.exe does not assemble in 64-bit mode. However, ML64.exe can assemble code for 64-bit mode. You can test this by using a 64-bit specific instruction, such as MOVSQ (Move qword from RSI to RDI).

Comment: I'm sorry for my poorly worded title, but you answered my question quite eloquently. Thank you!